# Let LLVM choose int size depend on platform

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm writing a compiler and I want my front end has little to do with the platform details, especially the size of the proto-types(int, long, etc).

For now, if I create a `int` variable, I have to use `IntegerType::get(mod->getContext(), 32)`. By using this, I have to know the platform information and set a `32` or `16`.

Since I want my front end has little to do with platform, is there any mechanism to let LLVM choose a size for a type for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite what you want, but LLVM does have a mechanism for asking the target platform about sizes, called [DataLayout](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DataLayout.html). Here's some code I use to generate debug info:

```
const DataLayout & dl = getModule().getDataLayout();
uint sizeInBits = 0;
if(...)
  sizeInBits = dl.getStructLayout(getObjectStructType())->getSizeInBits();
...
```

DataLayout doesn't offer a single size for ints, because [the CPU may may have several](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DataLayout.html#a4865a13a415f04576388b969d04d1541), as the current members of the Intel 4004 family do.

IIRC all of the current members offer 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit ints using more-or-less extended versions of the same registers (AL, AX, EAX, RAX), with the same performance for all operations except reading/writing to memory. But you can [ask LLVM which ones of 16/32/48/64 are good](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DataLayout.html#a4865a13a415f04576388b969d04d1541) and then pick an int size that suits you.

Comment: Hi, does that mean I send 16/32/64 respectively to `isLegalInteger()`, and the one which returns `true` is the "base" int size, then I can use this size to decide long, short, etc?

Comment: Yes. Except that more than one of them may return true, and that on the most common processors more than one of them actually does return true, because these processors actually do support several int sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Since "int" is a C/C++ feature, then its size is specified by C/C++ platform ABI. clang knows the necessary sizes / alignments for sure, so you'd need to integrate with C/C++ frontend one way or another (e.g. execute clang once to derive the necessary sizes).

Comment: So normally a front end should decide the size of an integer type, right?

Comment: @reavenisadesk yes, because it's the frontend job to know the details of the corresponding language :)